# Creation of classes in Factory design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

In the factory design pattern, we write logic for deciding which class to be loaded in the factory class. Suppose I have a choice of 100 classes, so for all 100 do I need to write conditions in factory class? Or there is some other way?

Comment: 100 classes in a factory?  You've done something very wrong.  There's no other way.  Time to refactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I'd create an annotation which describes the condition each class must meet to be created. Then I'd use reflection to discover all possible products and store a specific subfactory in a HashMap with the condition used as key.

Answer (score 0):

Its not very helpful, but I would say it totally depends on your use-case. There could be some generic logic on which a particular class could be picked up.

On a side note: I would advice you to rethink on the design if such situation occurs and not fix a problem which could be avoided to begin with. Use of reflection could help if your logic is around class name but again it could be an overkill for the problem.

Comment: Which design pattern I shoul switch to? So as to provide a generic logic for my hundred classes to get generated?

Comment: I cannot recommend a design pattern without understanding your use-case.